# Received duplicate pseudo-header field b':path' error when I send http2 requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http2

I have a url that only responds to http2 requests.

When I want send http/2 request with python to the URL, I get bellow `ERROR`:

> `h2.exceptions.ProtocolError: Received duplicate pseudo-header field b':path'`

My `Code`:

```
from hyper.contrib import HTTP20Adapter
import requests
MyHeader={
    
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

adapter = HTTP20Adapter(headers=MyHeader)
sessions=requests.session()
sessions.mount(prefix='https://myurl.com', adapter=adapter)
r=sessions.get('Continue_My_Url_response')
print(r)
```

I use too many `requests` library for `HTTP/1` and  this is first time I want work with `HTTP/2`.

Any body have idea and example for send this request over `HTTP/2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use httpx with http/2 support enabled: `httpx.Client(http2=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jerion5562 :

I use below code and worked:

First: Install library `pip install httpx[http2]`

```
import httpx
client = httpx.Client(http2=True)
response =  client.get(My_Url,headers=MyHeader)
print(response.http_version) # HTTP/2
print(response.status_code) # 200
```